# How to replace MATLAB's timeseries and synchronize functions in Octave?

Tags: octave

I have a MATLAB script that I would like to run in Octave. But it turns out that the `timeseries` and `synchronize` functions from MATLAB are not yet implemented in Octave. So my question is if there is a way to express or replace these functions in Octave.
For understanding, I have two text files with different row lengths, which I want to synchronize into one text file with the same row length over time. The content of the text files is:

Text file 1:

1st column contains the distance

2nd column contains the time

Text file 2:

1st column contains the angle

2nd column contains the time

Here is the part of my code that I use in MATLAB to synchronize the files.

```
ts1 = timeseries(distance,timed);
ts2 = timeseries(angle,timea);
[ts1 ts2] = synchronize(ts1,ts2,'union');
distance = ts1.Data;
angle = ts2.Data;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**edit:**

Here are some example files.

[input distance](https://studntnu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/marci_ntnu_no/EcbvCDm9f5ZPpzdqhjkvlJkBwTfAjrxNt8JCMliaD6nPxA?e=GAapKe)

[input roation angle](https://studntnu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/marci_ntnu_no/EZyUGRp0BSdKlhV0OZsLaR8BCoJRZnuV2QfQFHJ0vhRymA?e=0F1KqL)

[output](https://studntnu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/marci_ntnu_no/EQGXoHTSW5BClb_kQ3WODQYBh3g2H6kjE5Oq0AQAf-So8A?e=2tuXem)

Comment: can you put a simple example of the intended input and output?

Comment: Hi, I have added some example files under my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronize function seems to create a common timeseries from two separate ones (here, specifically via their union), and then use interpolation (here 'linear') to find interpolated values for both distance and angle at the common timepoints.

An example of how to achieve this to get the same output in octave as your provided output file is as follows.

<sub>Note: I had to preprocess your input files first to replace 'decimal commas' with dots, and then 'tabs' with commas, to make them valid csv files.</sub>

```matlab
Distance_t = csvread('input_distance.txt', 1, 0);         % skip header row
Rotation_t = csvread('input_rotation_angle.txt', 1, 0);   % skip header row

Common_t   = union( Distance_t(:,2), Rotation_t(:,2) );

InterpolatedDistance = interp1( Distance_t(:,2), Distance_t(:,1), Common_t );
InterpolatedRotation = interp1( Rotation_t(:,2), Rotation_t(:,1), Common_t );

Output = [ InterpolatedRotation, InterpolatedDistance ];
Output = sortrows( Output, -1 );   % sort according to column 1, in descending order
Output = Output(~isna(Output(:,2)), :);   % remove NA entries
```

<sub>(Note, The step involving removal of NA entries was necessary because we did not specify we wanted extrapolation during the interpolation step, and some of the resulting distance values would be outside the original timerange, which octave labels as NA).</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that works for me but for my purpose the `sortrows` line is not necessary. However, it seems the `union` function works a bit different in Octave because I lose a lot of points compared to MATLAB (I have twice as many points in MATLAB for my time vector). I think this is not a big problem for me as I have still enough points left to work with.

Comment: @Marc it is unlikely that it works 'differently'. Perhaps it keeps duplicate timepoints instead of discarding them (which is what union is supposed to do).